# If record exists with values for 2 columns, ignore insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to modify this so that if someone tries to insert a record that already exists with the pageID and displayID, it will simply ignore the INSERT and reload the page, effectively making no change.

I have a unique index on my page_id and display_id columns but it still inserts duplicates here.

How can I fix this to properly keep from inserting duplicates and just ignoring the insert request?

```
$pageID = $_GET['pageID'];
$displayID = $_GET['displayID'];

$assignPage = "
INSERT IGNORE INTO display_to_page(page_id, display_id)
Values( '".$pageID."', '".$displayID."')
";

$performAssign = $mysqlConn->query($assignPage);


header("Location: displayPage.php?displayID=".$displayID);
exit;
```

Comment: Can you share the DDL used to create the index? Perhaps it's not defined correctly?

Comment: I just created it in workbench under indexes

Comment: Make sure page_id and display_id make a composite unique index

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique index on both columns, then duplicates should not be inserted into the table.

This would look like either `unique(page_id, display_id)` in the table definition (or similar constraint) or:

```
create unique index unq_display_to_page_2 on display_to_page(page_id, display_id);
```

Note that these constraints/indexes are on the `display_to_page` table.

With such an index/constraint in the database, MySQL will not allow duplicates into the table.

You should also check the ids being passed into the string.  In fact, you should switch to using parameters.  Perhaps bad characters are getting into the query string somehow.